# ReactJS: Is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, on hover i am changing the text color of a link, I was able to achieve what i needed, however, this looks too much of code for me, I believe there should be a better way. I am wondering if there is a better logic than this. Please suggest.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      link_su: false,
      link_si: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.hover_signup = document.getElementById("signup");
    this.hover_signin = document.getElementById("signin");

    this.hover_signup.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.colorChange);
    this.hover_signup.addEventListener("mouseleave", this._colorChange);

    this.hover_signin.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.colorChange);
    this.hover_signin.addEventListener("mouseleave", this._colorChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    //removing all event listeners.
  }

  colorChange = e => {
    if (e.target.id == "signup") {
      this.setState({ link_su: !this.state.link });
    } else {
      this.setState({ link_si: !this.state.link });
    }
  };

  _colorChange = e => {
    if (e.target.id == "signup") {
      this.setState({ link_su: this.state.link });
    } else {
      this.setState({ link_si: this.state.link });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <main role="main" className="inner cover">
        <a
          href="/signup"
          className="btn btn-lg btn-secondary"
          style={link_su ? { color: "white" } : { color: "#282c34" }}
          id="signup"
        >
          Sign Up
        </a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a
          href="/signin"
          className="btn btn-lg btn-secondary"
          style={link_si ? { color: "white" } : { color: "#282c34" }}
          id="signin"
        >
          Sign In
        </a>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey why don't you use css for this?

Comment: Don't ever do direct DOM manipulation (`getElementById`, `addEventListener`) while using a framework like React. Basically the whole point of such a framework is to allow you to describe such interactions declaratively.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you for the information but i ve seen few code where eventlistener been used.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond Specifically, `getElementById` and `addEventListener` don't do direct DOM manipulation, though they often be used alongside with manipulation methods.

Comment: @hindmost - yes I know strictly speaking they don't, but that's usually what they're used for. Now I've looked further and see the OP is just using `setState` in those methods, so this is probably OK - although imo it's not very idiomatic to do it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is an easier way, this can all be done with CSS using the `:hover` selector.

For example:

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

a.link1:hover {
  color: red;
}

a.link2:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a class="link1" href="">Link 1</a>
<a class="link2" href="">Link 2</a>
```

**Edit**:

If you use the style property to apply styles, I believe nothing (except `!important` properties) can override that style, so if you provide the initial color through style but the hover color in a stylesheet, then the hover color will be overridden by the initial style and not show up. So it's best not to mix in-line and stylesheet styles.

Here's an example of what happens:

```css
a.link1:hover {
  color: red;
}

a.link2:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<a class="link1" style="color: blue;" href="">Always Blue</a>
<a class="link2" style="color: blue;" href="">Using Important (but you shouldn't)</a>
```

Note: I'm really not recommending using the `!important` flag here, instead I'm recommending removing the in-line styles.

Comment: Make sure you import the css file ;) @Ash

Comment: @Ash: then ask a question about what you tried then, it's obviously a far better method.

Comment: CSS integration in React is not that straight forward! `className` shall be used instead of `class`, one can use CSS-in-JS or plain CSS, there is the issue of scoped CSS, etc etc etc!

Comment: @Ash There also might be something cascading over the style. When you use the `style` property to apply styles, I believe nothing (except `!important` properties) can override that style, so if you provide the initial color through `style` but the hover color in a stylesheet, then the hover color will be overridden by the initial style and not show up. Is this the case?

Comment: @HenryWoody Yes that is the case, I removed the style attribute completely from the link and it is working now.